# How do I enable the Windows 7 taskbar hover preview?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, preview

In Windows 7, when you hover over an application in your task bar, a preview is generated showing the contents of the application window.

Another option just displays the names of the windows.

Somehow, I've turned off the preview and it only displays the window names. How do I change it back?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Right Mouse Click on the taskbar, go to properties and on the first tab, make sure 'Show window previews (thumbnails) is checked.

Comment: This looks like vista taskbar properties http://www.techiecorner.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/disable-taskbar-preview-pane-270x300.jpg  Where it says "Show window previews".   But this looks like Windows 7 taskbar properties http://beingpc.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/How-to-Avoid-Taskbar-Application-Icons-Grouping-in-Windows-7.jpg  Notice the Windows 7 one does not have "Show Window previews".

Comment: @barlop So how to enable this feature?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde Try another answer. The answerer doesn't know one windows version from another, and the questioner doesn't understand when something is or isn't an answer. If you're on Windows Vista try what he wrote and see how it goes. If you're on Windows 7, go for the answer on here like the other two that have 6+ votes

Answer (score 13):

Right click on *Computer » Properties » Advanced system settings » Advanced tab » Performance settings*. Here, uncheck/check 'enable desktop composition'.

This will disable/enable preview of windows on the taskbar.

None of the Aero Peek settings or registry edits work.

WARNING: this will result in many other changes and cannot be easily undone.

Comment: Whoa, wait a second there. Enabling/disabling desktop composition will affect many things, not just the taskbar preview. Notably, most Aero-branded effects and flicker prevention when moving windows.

Answer (score 8):

You need to enable Aero

Right click on your desktop -> personalize

Edit : Or you have recently installed an application that dosen't suport Aero, so you can't reenable it.

Comment: I am using Aero. I think this is what actually happened... something I installed (can't remember now what it was) disabled it.

Thanks!

Comment: Since I can't answer the question directly, I'll post what worked for me here:  Try checking your video card's driver.  If the driver is out of date, that'll prevent Aero from drawing the thumbnails.  I fixed the problem with a video card update.

Comment: More useful information here: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-turn-on-and-enable-aero-in-windows-7-enable-aero-peek/

Answer (score 1):

For me this was solved by copying (or rather screenshotting) all settings in "personalization", then activating the "Windows 7" theme, applying all settings again and then saving that as a theme.